# VueJs computed property without template binding

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a component with computed in it. Computed named 'getVuexValue' takes value from vuex store through getters (getSomeData):

```js
 computed: {
     getVuexValue() {
            return this.$store.getters.getSomeData;
        }
 }
```

It works fine when I put {{getVuexValue}} into my template. Data updates when value in vuex store was changed. But I dont need to use model binding here, so my question is: Is there a way to track updates in computed property without binding it to template model?

Comment: By "track updates in computed property", you could watch that property for changes with a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure

```
watch: {
    getVuexValue(newValue, oldValue) {
        // whatever...
    }
},
```